# How to convert "Wed Jan 26 2022" to date in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have varchar like this "Wed Jan 26 2022"
I need to convert this to date in sql. How can i do this

Comment: depends on your sql engine

Comment: Every SQL product (rdbms) has different functions to handle type conversions; you need to specify what you are using; and also specify if the day name and month name are always three characters long.

Comment: day name and month will always be 3 characters.

Comment: You have a previous question that was ultimately tagged for SQL Server, so presumably this is also for that product - please edit this question and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: _day name and month will always be 3 characters_ In what language? This should demonstrate you need to think more clearly and precisely about your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for Sql Server:

```
convert(date, substring('Wed Jan 26 2022',5,11),9)
```

we ignore the Day name (superfluous), and convert the rest using format 9 indicating Mon dd yyyy format.

Comment: Can you please tell me what those fields 5,11 and 9 mean?

Comment: Sure, 5 (the second parameter of substring function) tells as to start extracting the string from position 5 (letter 'J' of Jan, in your string), 11 tells the same function to extract 11 characters, so substring('Wed Jan 26 2022',5,11) gives 'Jan 26 2022'. 9 is a constant telling SqlServer's CONVERT function what format to expect (search for SqlServer CAST and CONVERT)

Comment: Convert is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. This will be different in different database products/SQL dialects.

Comment: Substring is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. You can expect this function to be the same in most database products.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation..!

Answer (score 0):

SQL*plus server (Here's my code) -
If I am right, you want such type of string which is an invalid one to convert that into a valid one so that you can store valid data into the database. then this code you can use->

```
SELECT TO_DATE('WED JAN 26 2022','DY MON DD YYYY')FROM DUAL;
```

(Explanation)->
Code will convert invalid date datatype to a valid date data type which is used in Oracle(SQL).

DY = Abbreviated Week Day

DD = Month day indicator

MON = Abbreviated month

YYYY = Four-digit year indicator

Comment: Lol, `SQL*plus server`. As if `MySql Server` wasn't bad enough to confuse with `MS Sql Server`.